# Creating an RPM package consisting only of required packages

Tags: rpm, rhel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm currently updating a handful of my machines. I created my own patch type package that I've been installing on top of my existing RHEL 6 machines. However, some of the machines I'm supporting have installed random packages over the months, and some of my updates fail because of mismatched versions.

Please correct me if this is a stupid approach to this!

My approach to verifying that the machines have the correct packages and versions is to make a blank RPM package, that doesn't install anything, but *requires* a list of packages. That way, if I install that RPM, I'll know immediately if the versions are off. I know I can set required packages in the spec file with the "requires" option. What can I fluff the SOURCES directory with, in order to create that RPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just touch an empty file, or even use a virtual provides. Pretty sure no sources is valid, just say something like `Provides: our_required_software = %{version}`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to put any files in your package (nor in the SOURCES directory) for it to work; something as minimalistic as this works:

```
Name:       test
Version:    0.1.0
Release:    0
License:    Proprietary
Summary:    meta package
Group:      Applications
Requires:   vim
BuildArch:  noarch

%description
%{summary}

%build

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%install

%files
```